# I've broken command not found?

Tags: 14.04, bash, python

I was messing around with bower, npm, and node, as I was trying to upgrade ember-cli, and I broke something strange.

I get the following python error whenever I type a command that is not found in the terminal. Can anyone help me diagnose the problem?

```
my@my_machine:~$ a # or anything else that is not an installed program or bash command
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-gdbm package')
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm', please install the python3-gdbm package


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gdbm
ImportError: No module named 'gdbm'
```

I've tried to reinstall:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-gdbm 
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-gdbm
```

But that doesn't change anything.

Comment: have you accidentally uninstalled python3-gdbm?  maybe reinstall it? sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-gdbm

Comment: @fossfreedom Just tried that, no help, thanks.

Comment: did you try `set +o xtrace`?

Comment: Just tried it, didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was connected to my recent upgrade to python 3.5.0. Reverted to 3.4.3, and it works now.