# Cannot create Python 3.5 virtualenv ImportError: No module named 'gdbm'

Tags: 14.04, python, python3, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm experiencing the same issue as this individual but unfortunately switching back to Python 3.4 is not an option for me, I need to be running 3.5.

[I've broken command not found?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694682/ive-broken-command-not-found)

Here is what I'm trying

```
mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 test_env
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-gdbm package')
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm', please install the python3-gdbm package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
     from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gdbm
ImportError: No module named 'gdbm'
```

Comment: perhaps you should try reinstalling libgdbm, libgdbm-dev and python3.5

Comment: Did you install the python3-gdbm package?

Answer (score 1):

I have python 3.6 install and working i have tried many things but

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-gdbm
```

This command worked for me
for python 3.5  you shold use

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-gdbm
```